# Python - Array of separate memory location changes when I alter original array

Tags: python, arrays

I am beginning a code to create an array of coordinates of an FCC lattice. Here is my code so far, with helpful print statements:

```
def init_FCC(a, x_rep,y_rep,z_rep):
    n_atoms = 4*x_rep*y_rep*z_rep
    UC = array([[0, 0, 0],[(a/2),(a/2),0],[(a/2), 0, (a/2)],[0,(a/2),(a/2)]])
    coords = UC[:]
    print(array_equal(coords,UC))
    for n in range(x_rep):
        if array_equal(coords,UC) == False:
            coords = vstack((coords, UC))
        UC[:,0] += a
        print(UC,id(UC))
        print(coords,id(coords),'\n',60*'*')
    return(coords)
```

When using the function, for example a=5, x_rep=3, the print statements indicate that the if statement is never True, i.e. the arrays 'UC' and 'coords' are always the same. But as you can see, directly after the if statement I alter the first column of UC, but not coords, each time the for loop iterates. I checked the ids of each to ensure they are different memory locations. Why is the array coords changing when I alter UC, and how do I prevent this? As an after-note, I know this is probably not the best way to accomplish my end goal of creating an FCC lattice but I wanted to make my own code.

Thanks.

Comment: You are reassigning `coords` right here: `coords = vstack((coords, UC))`, hence the new memory location.

Comment: None of `array`, `array_equal` or `v_stack` are defined.

Comment: array, array_equal, and vstack are all numpy functions. As I stated in the question, the if statement is never True and the vstack operation is never executed. I verified this with separate print statements, apologies for not including that.

Answer (score 1):

when you do `varr_array2 = var_array1` you are just creating a new "label" for the same object, see these examples:

```
a = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]])
b = a

print (a is b)
True

c = a.copy()
print (a is c)
False

b[0] = [0,0,0]
print (a)
[[0 0 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]]

c[0] = [9,9,9]
print (a)
[[0 0 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]]

print(c)
[[9 9 9]
 [1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]]
```

Conclusion: Use `array.copy()`.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works. However, I still do not understand why using
    coords = UC[:]
or 
    coords = list(UC)
do not work. According to their ids, they are separate objects. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

`coords = UC[:]` provides an alternative *view* on the array, not a copy of it. You need `coords = UC.copy()`.